# get real static file path with the url

Tags: django

I want to know is there a build-in function to get the real file path with a url of the static file?
For example:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('job',os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "job")),
)
```

I have a file named a.txt, stores in /job/subfolder/a.txt. The url should be /static/job/subfolder/a.txt. Now think about it in a reverse way. I know the url:/static/job/subfolder/a.txt, what I want to do is find the real path ,i.e. /job/subfolder/a.txt. I am wandering is there a build-in function handle such task?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need for special function. Just get substring of absolute url:

```
relative_url = absolute_url[len(STATIC_URL):]
```